# How to apply an array of css attributes with a method, without chaining/jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm currently running the following code to apply an array of css attributes to mimic jquery (I'm not allowed to use jquery) but the loop is only grabbing the first node:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.css = function(attr) {
    for(i in attr){
        return this.style[i] = attr[i];
    }
}

button.css({
    'width': '58px',
    'height': '55px',
    'font-family': 'century gothic',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'padding-left': '2px',
    'padding-top': '0',
    'outline': 'none'
});
```

What is wrong with my loop?

Comment: this should not be tagged jquery because you dont accept jquery solution

Comment: nothing is executed after the `return` which breaks the `for` loop

Comment: _"only grabbing the first node"_ ? Can you make us run the demo ?

Comment: @Suazi that's because you are returning inside the loop, so only the first iteration will be completed and only the first element of css will be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is exited as soon as the first loop executes due to the `return` statement. Move the `return` outside of the loop:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.css = function(attr) {
    for (i in attr) {
        this.style[i] = attr[i];
    }
    return this; // return the original element to enable chaining
}

var button = document.getElementById('foo');
button.css({
    'width': '58px',
    'height': '55px',
    'font-family': 'century gothic',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'padding-left': '2px',
    'padding-top': '0',
    'outline': 'none'
});
```

```html
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
```

Comment: Using the CSS style names is fine in this case as they are being applied through bracket notation, not the `style` object property directly. Either would work though.

Comment: Ooh yes.. True!...+1

Comment: No problem, glad to help